# Collection View animation :Expand Colllection View and Cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

While presenting Collection View , Collection View's frame should expand from zero to full screen Size. Along with that the cells in collection view should also animate from zero size to some particular size. Can anybody suggest how do I do that?

Comment: Can you post your animation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a delegate to the collection view's `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implement

`collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

to return a size that's proportional to the overall collection view's size, but that won't resize the *contents* of the cells. You may be better off doing the following:

1. [Take a *snapshot* of the full-size collection view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:).
2. Add the snapshot to the view that contains the collection view.
3. Remove the collection view, preserving its constraints to its parent somewhere, if necessary.
4. Set the snapshot's size to `(0,0)`.
5. Animate it to its full size.
6. In the animation's `completionHandler`, remove the
   snapshot view and re-add the collection view, re-adding the collection view's constraints.